# Which user can I set up a new user in Oracle 11.2.0?

Tags: oracle11g

Which user can I set up a new user in Oracle 11.2.0 ?

i connect with scott/tiger as normal (i cant connect with sysdba)

how i can create new user ?

how to connect with power user for this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Gali-

Out of the box the Scott user lacks the required privileges to create users and/or connect as sysdba.

Using the command line sqlplus utility:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

This will log you in as the SYS user on the database for which you want to create the new user.  From here you can issue your standard

```
CREATE USER foo IDENTIFIED BY bar;
```

Alternatively, when you setup and installed the database, you should have been prompted for a SYS user password.  You can use this account to log in via a GUI (say Toad or SQL Developer) using the "SYSDBA" connection property.

Hope this helps.

-CJ